# Duplicate word detection of speech algorithm or code in android

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

Is there a reference code or algorithm that do the duplicate words detection of speech? So that in this kind of algorithm the most often words said by somebody in a certain time can be found out. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is it you do not understand?  Turning sound into text?  Detecting common words in the text?  They are quite different problems.

Comment: Actually is a combination of both, not only do i want to turn sound into text, but also the detection of the pop up frequency of certain words.